# Conda fails to install VEP

Tags: installation, conda

I'm trying to install VEP in a conda environment, but it keeps failing. I've tried with the normal installation process:

```
conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep
```

But get the below errors which run for about an hour and eventually fail:

```
$ conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | ^[failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
```

I've also tried creating a new environment and installing, but still fail.

```
conda create -n ensembl-vep -c conda-forge -c ensembl-vep
```

Any more ideas anyone??

Comment: What OS? Bioconda doesn't support Windows, and Mamba reports missing the `t_coffee` dependency for **osx-64**. Basically, this seems to only be operational on **linux-64** platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The following YAML works for me on **linux-64** and **osx-64** platforms:

**vep.yaml**

```yaml
name: vep
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
  - etetoolkit  # this provides a t_coffee build for osx
dependencies:
  - ensembl-vep
```

**Environment Status:** [image: vep]

However, for **osx-64** I found that `channel_priority` must be set to `flexible`, otherwise Conda Forge masks some required packages that must be sourced from Bioconda channel.

```bash
CONDA_CHANNEL_PRIORITY=flexible mamba env create -n vep -f vep.yaml
```